# installing visual studio 2012 microsoft visual c++ 2012 compilers package failed

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2012

I tried installing visual studio 2012 and it always fails.

[image]

"Setup Failed!
Install cannot continue because some required components failed

...

X Visual Studio Core Features
  Fatal error during installation.

! Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Compilers
  Package failed."

I'm running on Windows 7 x86 up to date

Comment: The 2nd link lets you see the log file.  What does it say?

Comment: The question is, quite obviously, how do we fix this error from happening?  I'm getting this error too.  The log file is not helpful.  [Microsoft lists it as a bug, but no with no resolution.](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/773202/microsoft-visual-c-2012-core-libraries-package-failed)

Comment: I just fixed it by finding and removing the folder in `C:\Program Data\Package Cache\` that was relevant to the package that was causing me a problem and then running Repair on Visual Studio 2012 in Programs & Features.  This will re-download that particular component.  I found the relevant folder guid from an online post.

Comment: This question should be re-opened, in my opinion, because it is a developer-specific question that is specific to this error.